# WPF: When/where are Collection Views created for a bound collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm familiar with the concept that a collection used for a WPF Binding (for example, ItemsSource) actually uses the default collection view for that collection, but I am looking for some clarification on where that happens.  Potentially depending on that answer, what is the recommended way to implement similar binding behavior if I am creating my own UserControl that has its own property like ItemsSource and I want to use ICollectionView functionality on it within my UserControl?

So if my UserControl has a ItemsSource property like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestPropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TestProp", typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable), typeof(MyUserControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, TestPropChanged, null));
```

And my XAML uses it like this:

```
<local:MyUserControl TestProp="{Binding MyCollection}"/>
```

Let's say MyCollection is of type ConfigCollection, my own type, derived from ObservableCollection.  From MyUserControl's perspective, the binding sets TestProp to an object of type ConfigCollection (NOT a Collection View object).

The MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-to-collections
Under "Using a default view", state:

> WPF also creates a default collection view for every collection used as a binding source. If you bind directly to a collection, WPF binds to its default view.

That seems to be pretty universal, so in my case I was thinking it might be set as a Collection View whose source was MyCollection, but that is not the case.

So, does the "magic" of translating a collection into its default collection view all happen within each control's code?  Is there a recommended way of making sure my ItemsSource can accept either a collection (and use the default view) or accept a Collection View and then use that specific view rather than the default?

Comment: The collection view sits in between the source property and the `IEnumerable` target property. There is nothing you need to in your code to enable this. Your `TestProp` can be set or bind to any `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working that way.  `MyUserControl` receives a ConfigCollection in the above example, not a collection view.  If in `MyUserControl` I wanted to call `ICollectionView.MoveCurrentToNext` on `TestProp` as of now there is no ICollectionView to do it on.  Does `MyUserControl` need to test and see whether `TestProp` was set to a collection (and call `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` on it) or a Collection View?  ItemsControl's seem to handle this transparently.

Comment: Take a look at the Reference Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,a69fc295c0a429d0 and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemCollection.cs,12713dfc3e013edc. This is definitely handled in the target control. You may want to derive yours from ItemsControl.

Comment: If you want to work explicitly with a CollectionView (for xample for sorting, filtering, grouping) use a `CollectionViewSource` in XAML. And bind the `ItemsSource` (or TestProp in your example) to that CollectionViewSource.
Than you have by the way a non-default collection view (which is different from the one returned by GetDefaultView)

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but then the value of `ItemsSource` has two different scenarios in `MyUserControl` code:  In the first case, it's an object of type `ConfigCollection` (or whatever collection is being used) and in the second case it's an object of type `ListCollectionView`.  My question is the recommended/standard way to respond to those two different scenarios, and I'm thinking it boils down to calling `GetDefaultView` in the first, but not the second.

Comment: And actually I'm noticing if you call `GetDefaultView` on a `ListCollectionView` it just returns the same view, so really in `MyUserControl` you can call `GetDefaultView` on whatever `ItemsSource` (or `TestProp`) happens to be and it will return the correct view to work with either way.

Comment: I guess I originally misunderstood MS docs like I linked to in my question and also this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 that states "**WPF always binds to a view rather than a collection**".  In reality, there's nothing stopping you from binding a collection to a property of your control.  Your control will see it as the collection that it is, not a view of it.  It seems what MS is describing is the how the code of MS's controls respond when a collection (rather than a view) is bound to `ItemsSource`.